# How to align title and button on the same line in Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a title and a button. The title should be left-aligned and the button should be right-aligned.

My problem is that the title and the button are too high. Is it possible to fix this via bootstrap?

[image]

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
   <h1>This is a title</h1>
   <div class="flex-grow-1">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end flex-wrap">
         <button type="button" (click)="goBack()" class="btn-green">
         Back
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="separator-breadcrumb border-top"></div>
```

Here is a reproduction -> [here](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%20%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EHTML%20CSS%20JS%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20Bootstrap%20CSS%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20href=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20integrity=%22sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%0A%20%20%20%20/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22styles.css%22%20/%3E%0A%20%20%3C/head%3E%0A%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cbr%20/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22container%20wrapper-component%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22breadcrumb%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EThis%20is%20a%20title%3C/h1%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22flex-grow-1%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22d-flex%20align-items-center%20justify-content-end%20flex-wrap%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20type=%22button%22%20(click)=%22goBack()%22%20class=%22btn-green%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Back%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/button%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22separator-breadcrumb%20border-top%22%3E%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22row%20pt-5%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22card%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22card-body%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EThis%20is%20a%20paragraph%3C/p%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C/div%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E%0A&css=.wrapper-component%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%2095%25;%0A%20%20margin:%200%20auto;%0A%7D%0A%0A.btn-green%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20150px;%0A%20%20height:%2050px;%0A%20%20border:%20none;%0A%20%20border-radius:%2050px;%0A%20%20background:%20#3cc064;%0A%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%20%20font-weight:%20600;%0A%20%20margin:%2010px%205px%2010px%200;%0A%20%20text-transform:%20uppercase;%0A%20%20cursor:%20pointer;%0A%7D%0A%0A.btn-green:hover%20%7B%0A%20%20background:%20#79df4a;%0A%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%7D%0A&js=//%20JavaScript%0Adocument.getElementById(%27welcome%27).innerText%20+=%20%0A%22%20Editors%22;%0A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to align the bottom of your title with the bottom of your button you can simply add `align-self-end` class to your title:

```html
<div class="breadcrumb">
   <h1 class="align-self-end">This is a title</h1>
   <div class="flex-grow-1">
      <button></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or you can also set it globally on your breadcrumb :

```html
<div class="breadcrumb align-items-end">
   <h1>This is a title</h1>
   <div class="flex-grow-1">
      <button></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I misunderstood your problem and it it just to reduce the gap at the top of separator just do `<div class="breadcrumb mb-0">` to remove the bottom margin.